# SN1 like reaction acid-cataylzed hydrolysis of epoxide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, hydrolysis

What would be the reaction mechanism for the reaction between epoxide and $\ce{H2SO4}$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your question could do with some more data. Here is my answer based on what I *think* you mean:

---

You ought to get a glycol.

[image]

First, a proton from the acidic medium attacks the neucleophile, $\ce{O}$. This creates a positively charged trivalent oxygen. The electrons in one of the two $\ce{C-O}$ bonds transfer to the $\ce{O+}$, breaking the bond and effectively transferring the positive charge to the carbon.

At this point, note that the carbocation thus formed may [rearrange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbocation_rearrangement).

Now, we have the nucleophilic attack. An oxygen atom (specifically the lone pair of an oxygen) from a nearby water molecule attacks the carbocation, forming another trivalent positively charged oxygen. This is deprotonated, giving the final glycol product.

Here's the same mechanism,  showing movement of electrons (pairs):

[image]

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Wrt [this 2010 journal](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp9106316?journalCode=jpcafh), note that " In the SN1 mechanism, the existence of the typical carbocation was not observed" This is in direct contrast to your statement: "At this point, note that the carbocation thus formed may rearrange." Please can you fix this. Thank you!