# Will a strained three membered ring open up when exposed to heat or acids/base?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I was wondering if a three membered ring or a three membered epoxide would ever open up spontaneously when exposed to heat, or acids/bases?

I would think at some point, but will it routinely happen to a three membered epoxide?

Comment: Well, the whole thing is pretty strained, so yes, it would snap open quite easily.

Comment: Definitely, three membered rings are extremely strained. The bond angle is extremely small.

Comment: There no other oxiranes (epoxides) but three-membered rings! On the opening with bases, see http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27288/do-epoxide-rings-react-with-bases/27290, on the opening under acidic conditions see http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2655/sn1-like-reaction-acid-cataylzed-hydrolysis-of-epoxide and http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4305/regioselectivity-of-acid-catalyzed-ring-opening-of-epoxides

Comment: I realized I added acids/bases into the question, but could anyone tell me if there is any info on spontaneous opening as heat increases in solution